# Data not inserting into database when using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am learning pdo and i tried to play with CRUD method. I am trying to insert data into database using pdo but it isn't inserting. Below is my code

```
        <?php 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT ));
try {
    $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(?,?)");
        $query->execute(array($username, $password));
        echo "data";
    }
    catch (PDOException $event) {
        echo $event->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

i have this index file named as index.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'db.php';
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
</head>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == '$_POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        require 'login.php';
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        require 'register.php';
    }
}
?>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my db.php looks like

```
<?php 
try {
$connect = new PDO('mysql:dbname=pdologin;host=localhost', 'root', '$$$$'); 
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $event) {
    $event->getMessage();

}
?>
```

Comment: Is `$connect` a PDO connection or `mysqli`? Don't escape with prepared statements you are suppose to parameterize the query. `VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: What's with the `mysqli_real_escape_string` calls then? Where's the `error_reporting`?

Comment: $connect is pdo connection

Comment: Okay, so you can't use any `mysqli` functions. Remove those. Parameterize the query and bind the values you were escaping. The driver will escape them for you. You can bind with `bindparam`, or by passing them in the `execute` function.

Comment: i removed them but not working

Comment: no errors? try placing your code inside a `try...catch` and use `PDOException` as the handler.

Comment: With the update you are open to SQL injections. Prepared statements alone do nothing to prevent injections. `"INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(?, ?)` and then `$query->execute(array($username, $password))`

Comment: updated code still not working

Comment: You again didn't fix the query..

Comment: echo your `$e->getMessage();` what does it return?

Comment: it doesn't return anything

Comment: @user3783243 please edit my code then

Comment: I did, 5 minutes ago and 13 minutes ago. Please read the comments fully. The `?`s are literally what you need, not samples. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: if nothing is happening when you `echo $e->getMessage();` then its never reading the `catch` block, meaning your code isnt running at all, or it is running successfully in the `try` block. Try to `echo` anything inside the `try` section, just to see that you are at least getting something there.

Comment: nothing is showing. It doesn't echoing anything at all

Comment: Check the error log, status code of the page, and the source of the page.

Comment: nothing is happenig at all. the page only reloads and shows nothing

Comment: if nothing echos than your problem is that PHP is not working, perhaps your servers down or your not using `.php` on the page your working on. Are you familiar with the terminal? through it you can try running `php -a name-of-your-file.php` to see if anything happens

Comment: turn on `error_reporting`, perhaps this is off and thus not showing you any errors.

Comment: i am using localhost and everything is working fine. the problem is only with this code. Let me add the full code. please check the question again

Comment: My guess is that `$connect` is undefined

Comment: so in `index.php` I see you have `require_once 'db.php'`, then inside db.php you create the `$connect` object ... once `index.php` has that object, where is it used? where does your original code fit in? is it `login.php`/`register.php`?

Comment: i am inserting data so the object `$connect` is used in register.php.

Comment: lol I left the correct answer below first, yet you accepted someone else's answer who posted the same answer after mine. Thanks.. sigh..

Comment: i just saw his answer and it worked so accepted his answer. either way you helped me very and my doubts are now clear

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code never reaches your `require` scripts (`login.php` or `register.php`) because your conditional is incorrect.

You have: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == '$_POST')`

It should be `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to end up with something like below while learning or doing some small script that will need a connection, in the long run wrapping this stuff in a function or using a small helper or framework can make this a little easy. Great idea to learn but its still tedious boiler plate no matter how many years you write this stuff.

```
<?php
//db settings that are typically in a config somewhere
$db_servername = "localhost";
$db_username = "username for your database";
$db_password = "password for your database";
$db_name = "your_db_name";        

try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_servername;dbname=$db_name, $db_username, $db_password");
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
 }catch(PDOException $e){
    //echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
 $sth = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username,:password)");

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT );

 $sth->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->execute();
```

as a example my team now just writes database binding code like

```
<?php
//array of ids to insert
$binds['ids'] = array(1,3,4,5,6,7,9,08098);
//Database class is auto included with every script
$success = Database::query('insert into my_table (id) values(:ids)',$binds);
```

Answer (score 0):

connect first

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","my_db");
```

then remove the parameters when executing

```
$query->execute();
```

try this

```
   <?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","my_db");
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT );
    try {
        $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')");
        $query->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```